# What should One learn first? Java Collection Frameworks or Data structures and Algorithms?

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, data-structures

I have learnt the basics of Java language and now can program easily in Java. Now I want to know that whether should I learn Java Collection Frameworks first or Data Structures and Algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn first Data Structures and algorithms because now technology generation  in every selection interview are based on these two things Structures and algorithms . These is very important now for every developer select any programming with data structure and algorithms
Because all method of data structure and algorithms are apply during big project its necessary . if you have stamina so learn more hour and focused only this two then only structures and algorithms. Monday to Saturday (data structures and algorithms) and  Sunday
(Java collection ) you can learn java collection framework.  You can do it.
first data and algorithms is clear then we better understand easily java collection. hope you will get answer of your question.

Answer (score 1):

As though you can program easily in java so now you start learn some common data structure and algorithm then try to implement them with java. it will clear your concept. after completing those common ds and algo  then start java collection framework

Answer (score 0):

Obviously Data Structure and Algorithm first.

because those are the only way to get understand with the frameworks.

best of luck brother.